# Application has been blocked from accessing graphics hardware on 3D games

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have Windows 10 with Radeon HD 5670. Since month or so all games using 3D graphics hang the error message `Application Has Been Blocked From Accessing Graphics Hardware`

This is similar thing to [application-has-been-blocked-from-accessing-graphics-hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/1055165/application-has-been-blocked-from-accessing-graphics-hardware),  just it hangs with all the 3D games.

Games I tried: Lego Harry Potter, Minecraft, Test Drive Unlimited. It takes no more than two minutes to have the screen blinking for several seconds and games crash.

I tried some googled out solutions, like:

- graphic card driver update
- removing all graphics drivers with DDU utility from guru3d
- ran System File Checker and DISM commands as described [here](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-application-has-been-blocked-from-accessing-graphics-hardware-error-on-windows-10/)
- editing TdrDelay in registry as described in fix 3 [here](https://www.kapilarya.com/display-driver-stopped-responding-and-has-recovered-windows-10)

I thought it may be some hardware issue, took out the graphics card, cleaned it up from dust, installed awesome http://openhardwaremonitor.org/ and MSI Kombustor (v3 didn't worked for me for some reason, but v2 worked fine). Kombustor shown this is no overheating nor hardware issue, as tests ran from it took everything from GPU without hanging anything and temperature below 70 Celsius. And games crashed without much load at low temperatures.

And everything worked all fine just a month ago. Maybe some windows update broke it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found somewhere a tip that it is Raptr application that causes trouble. I removed it already week ago or so and reinstalled the drivers afterwards. But during reinstallation I included ATI Catalyst Control Center again. Now when I uninstalled it, everything went back to normal. Without games or driver reinstallation.

Maybe ATI Catalyst Control Center is just part of the puzzle, but it seems it affected 3D graphics somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently just had this exact same error, however I am using a Nvidia Geforece GTX 660, so its a decently older card.  By any chance are you doing any kind of overclocking? This seemed to be the issue with my error.

I had my card overclocked and I recently updated the software that I was using to control the overclocking.  It turns with the updated software, the default settings were changed and it actually overclocked my GPU beyond the stable boost clock speed. This I believe caused instability in the card.

I actually first tried everything you already did except the registry check. I even replaced the thermal paste on my card, because I thought it might be overheating, although my temps weren't unusually high.  I finally just down clocked my GPU by about -55Mhz for the GPU clock and set my memory offset to about -15Mhz. This seemed to correct the issue.  I have now been able to play my games for several hours without an issue.

If you're not overclocking, then obviously this wont help you out, but this seemed to resolve my issue. Also this error should generate an entry in the Event Log.  Check and see what the error code is that it gives you.  I don't remember what mine was but I found the down clocking suggestion by searching for that code and it came up on a random forum.

Comment: Whats wrong with this answer? It was a solution that worked for the same error message.

Comment: Your GTX660 leaves my HD5670 way behind. No, I am not overclocking. Thanks for the EventLog tips.